# Botón en el border de la pantalla

Tags: android

quiero poner un botón el en borde izquiero de un fragment, este ultimo estará oculto a la derecha de la pantalla y solo se verá de su layout la mitad del botón antes mencionado. Cuando el botón sea presionado el fragment se animará hasta el otro borde de la pantalla y la mitad del botón que al principio se veía, ahora se ocultará mostrandose así la otra mitad para que el usuario puede revertir la animación del fragment. Mi problema es que no se como poner el botón en el fragment.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Espero puedan ayudarme gracias

Comment: Hola Elejota. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia porque has de mostarar lo intentado y explicar por qué no te funciona: erroes, problemas, resultado no esperado...Si no has intentado nada aun, has de investigar por tu cuenta e intentarlo. Si en el desarrollo tuvieras problemas, pregunta aqui siguiendo la guia [ask].Un saludo

Comment: Divide el problema en dos: Pon un botón en una pantalla que sea un semicírculo y por otro botón complementando en la otra pantalla

Comment: Gracias por responder pero, esa solución no me sirve. El efecto que quiero lograr es que sea un botón circular entero, y el semicirculo que se vería iniciamente no lo podré mover junto con el fragment cuando empiece a animarse.